# What are the potential risks in adding an "Ad" tracking image using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, document.write

I've been tasked to add some "[Doubleclick Spotlight](http://www.google.com/support/dfa/partner/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=28818&topic=28820&answer=186748)" tags to a number of pages on our site to aid in gathering data for an upcoming campaign.

Our site gets about 1 million unique visitors a month, so I'm always cautious about adding someone else's code to our repository.

Here's what the code looks like (and is intended to be placed inside our body tags).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var axel = Math.random() + "";
var a = axel * 10000000000000;
document.write('<img src="http://ad.doubleclick.net/activity;src=99999;type=foo315;cat=bar561;ord=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" alt=""/>');
</script>
<noscript>
<img src="http://ad.doubleclick.net/activity;src=99999;type=foo315;cat=bar561;ord=1?" width="1" height="1" alt="">
</noscript>
```

My question is this:  Does this introduce risk?  Could it block page loading or have some other adverse effect?  I can't think of anything obvious but would love your insights, experiences, or thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `document.write()` blocks further page load.

Comment: That is true, but could be misunderstood; only the adding of a new HTML node should be blocking.  Once it the IMG node itself is written to the DOM tree, and it triggers the resource request, that doesn't block further rendering of the page, but it could delay network requests.